# Constructor C# to return anonymous list

Tags: c#, .net

I have list which needs to be returned anonymous after passing anonymous list here is the code.

```
public GenericResponseModel(bool success, string reason, List<dynamic> model)
    {
        Success = success;
        Reason = reason;
        model = model;
    }
```

How do i return anonymous list as i will have anonymous model coming afterwards.

```
public ResponseWrapper<GenericResponseModel> GetVehicleChecklist()
    {
        List<VehicleChecklist> VehicleCheckList = this.database.VehicleChecklists.Select(y => y).ToList();
        if(VehicleCheckList != null)
        {
            IEnumerable<VehicleChecklistModel> mappedVehicleList = VehicleCheckList.MapVehicleCheckList();
            return new GenericResponseModel(true, string.Empty, mappedVehicleList);
        }}
```

I'm trying to get anonymous list from a that code.

Comment: Side note: `dynamic != anonymous`.

Comment: so your saying that i have to create each and every method every time to return list.

Comment: "I have list which needs to be returned anonymous after passing anonymous list here is the code." - I don't even understand what that means; can you clarify what you mean here, ideally with an example of how you would intend to use it if it worked the way you wanted?

Comment: Actually it was passing something like this public GenericResponseModel(bool success, string reason, object model = null)
        {
            Success = success;
            Reason = reason;
            Model = model;
        }

Comment: Now i need to pass a anonymous list after object model= null and return anonymous list @MarcGravell

Comment: yes, those are all words; now what does that *mean*? you can't *return* anything from a constructor - are you perhaps thinking of a static factory method? again, hence why I'm asking for an example of how you intend to use this, as it would make the context clearer

Comment: can't a constructor pass a anonymous list if not then i have to make a method for it as usual.

Comment: a constructor can't be generic, so if you're actually thinking of `List<T> model` for some anonymous `T`, then indeed, you can't do that in a constructor; but the *type* could be generic - it could be `GenericResponseModel<T>`, and there are ways of flipping into that to allow construction

Comment: Providing context is going to help you here as no one is sure what your intent is and what it is you are trying to accomplish. [edit] your question and include the code that will be using this which hopefully will provide additional information on your intent.

Comment: ok then i have to create a List<T> model for it.

Answer (score 2):

It *sounds* like you're trying to use a generic `<T>` to handle a list of an anonymous type; however, a constructor can't be generic, and the `Model` property would need to reflect the `T`. For this, you'd need to make the *type* generic, and proxy to it via a factory method to make it possible to use (since you can't `new` something if you can't speak the name); example:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

static class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var list = new[]
        {
            new { Id = 1, Name = "abc"},
            new { Id = 2, Name = "def"},
            new { Id = 3, Name = "ghi"},
        }.ToList();
        var response = GenericResponseModel.Create(true, "because", list);
    }
}
static class GenericResponseModel
{    // factory API to make it callable with an anonymous type
     public static GenericResponseModel<T> Create<T>(bool success, string reason,
        List<T> model) => new GenericResponseModel<T>(success, reason, model);
}
class GenericResponseModel<T>
{
    public GenericResponseModel(bool success, string reason, List<T> model)
    {
        Success = success;
        Reason = reason;
        Model = model;
    }

    public bool Success { get; }
    public string Reason { get; }
    public List<T> Model { get; }
}
```

---

You could also push the common properties down:

```cs
abstract class GenericResponseModel
{
    public bool Success { get; protected set; }
    public string Reason { get; protected set; }
    public static GenericResponseModel<T> Create<T>(bool success, string reason,
        List<T> model) => new GenericResponseModel<T>(success, reason, model);
}
class GenericResponseModel<T> : GenericResponseModel
{
    public GenericResponseModel(bool success, string reason, List<T> model)
    {
        Success = success;
        Reason = reason;
        Model = model;
    }
    public List<T> Model { get; }
}
```